Failed to read data from RDS using Glue Catalog table
When creating a visual ETL in AWS Glue, I encountered an issue where a Glue Catalog Table node failed to fetch data from RDS, despite using the same connection that successfully crawled the data. However, when I switched to using a MySQL node with the same RDS JDBC URL, it successfully read the data and stored it in S3. What could be the cause of this issue?
The read data from RDS should be uploaded to s3

Please share the error you are getting. If the connection is ok for crawling, it seems to be a IAM problem.

The problem has been resolved, actually when pasting a python script in the glue editor I supposed that it will select the RDS connection automatically as it does while making job via Visual editor but it was not the case & I have to expand advanced properties to select the relevant.
Thank you for your time

The problem has been resolved, actually when pasting a python script in the glue editor I supposed that it will select the RDS connection automatically as it does while making job via Visual editor but it was not the case & I have to expand advanced properties to select the relevant. Thank you for your time
